# Unable to fetch characters as in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Unable to fetch characters as in MySql database below is the table.

```
    Table1      
+-------------------------------+   
|   APH |   ID0                 |
+-------------------------------+   
|   A   |   Costa Rican Colón   |
|   B   |   Icelandic Króna     |
|   C   |   Somali Shilling     |
|   D   |   Nicaraguan Córdoba  |
+-------------------------------+
```

when i get the from db by using PDO in php
then the above character shown like this

Costa Rican Col�n

what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support UTF-8 completely in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application)

Comment: You need to set the correct character set when creating the database table (UTF-8 is recommended to support a wide range of accented characters).
Then see the link above for how to set this in your php code too.

Everything needs to be singing from same hymnsheet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching from mysql you need to use **htmlentities** like below in PHP

```
$str = htmlentities('Costa Rican Colón');
echo $str;exit;
```

Comment: Thanks it work fine i was freakout about this thanks a lot. @Golduno

Comment: it's my pleasure buddy, welcome, closed it too by clicking on tick mark

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetch data then using this function for character function.

```
function charConversion($string, $to = "HTML-ENTITIES", $from = 'UTF-8,ASCII,ISO-8859-9,ISO-8859-1') {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($string, $to, $from);
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    if (empty($str)) {
        return $string;
    }
    return $str;
}
```